# MS Excel Visual basic SQL query (multiple parameters and SQL string format)

Tags: sql, excel, vba

So, as the title states, what I'm trying to do is in MS Excel visual basic I'm trying to write all in visual basic a SQL query that connects to a database and there are multiple cells that act as parameters. Right now I'm focusing on just getting the query to return back the unfiltered results.
I found a very basic example located here...

[Awesome query that a fellow stackoverflow member made](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17618796/querying-a-table-in-excel-with-parameters-using-vba)

I just straight copied the code he was having problems with and tested it out with my database and a very simple query. This all works fine and dandy.

The issue that I'm running into is I have a little more complex SQL query that I need to use and I'm not quite sure on how the formatting should be in VB.

The SQL query that I need to run is listed below. The database that I'm using isn't very friendly either. When I try putting the entire query into the SQL string it gives me an error that just says SQL syntax error. And when I go to debug it shows the error on the .Refresh line. I realize this query is very large so I trimmed it down and made multiple lines in VB with double quotes marks around each sentence and combined them with & _. (See very bottom)

Anyone have any suggestions?

If anyone wants the full code, let me know but it's extremely similar to the link I posted above, just the ODBC connection information is different.

Thanks in advanced.

```
SELECT DISTINCT S.SAMPLENAME, S.SAMPLE_DESCRIPTION, B.BATCH_NAME, PR.PROC_NAME, S.SAMPLESTATE, S.SAMPLE_QTY,
                      (SELECT MMNT_NAME FROM apexalpha.CI_AAS_MEASUREMENTUNIT WHERE      (MEASUREMENTUNITID = S.SAMPLE_QTY_MEASUREMENTUNITID)) AS SAMP_MMNT_NAME, ACQP_CTABULAR.ASTIME, S.SAMPLE_DATE, 
                  ACQP_CTABULAR.EREAL, ACQP_CTABULAR.ELIVE, TRACER.CERT_NAME AS TRACER_CERT_NAME, S.TRACER_QTYFROM apexalpha.CI_AAD_BATCH AS B INNER JOIN
                  apexalpha.CI_AAD_SAMPLE AS S ON S.BATCHID = B.BATCHID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  apexalpha.CI_AAS_PROCEDURE AS PR ON B.PROCEDUREID = PR.PROCEDUREID AND B.REVISION = PR.REVISION LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  apexalpha.CI_AAD_SAMPLE_ANALYSIS AS A ON S.APPROVED_ANALYSISID = A.SAMPLE_ANALYSISID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  apexalpha.CI_AAR_CAM_ACQP1_RECORD AS ACQP1 ON A.SAMPLE_ANALYSISID = ACQP1.SAMPLE_ANALYSISID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  apexalpha.CI_AAR_CAM_PROC1_COMMON AS PROC1 ON A.SAMPLE_ANALYSISID = PROC1.SAMPLE_ANALYSISID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  apexalpha.CI_AAR_CAM_GEOM_RECORD AS GEOM ON A.SAMPLE_ANALYSISID = GEOM.SAMPLE_ANALYSISID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  apexalpha.CI_AAR_CAM_ACQP_CTABULAR AS ACQP_CTABULAR ON A.SAMPLE_ANALYSISID = ACQP_CTABULAR.SAMPLE_ANALYSISID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  apexalpha.CI_AAD_SAMPLE_RUN AS RUN ON RUN.CURRENT_ANALYSISID = S.APPROVED_ANALYSISID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  apexalpha.CI_AAS_CHAMBER AS C ON RUN.CHAMBERID = C.CHAMBERID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  apexalpha.CI_AAR_CAM_ANALCNTL1_COMMON AS ANCNTL ON A.SAMPLE_ANALYSISID = ANCNTL.SAMPLE_ANALYSISID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  apexalpha.CI_AAR_CAM_ANALCNTL2_COMMON AS ANCNTL2 ON A.SAMPLE_ANALYSISID = ANCNTL2.SAMPLE_ANALYSISID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  apexalpha.CI_AAR_CAM_NUCL_RTABULAR AS NUCL_TAB ON A.SAMPLE_ANALYSISID = NUCL_TAB.SAMPLE_ANALYSISID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  apexalpha.CI_AAR_CAM_NUCL_COMMON AS NUCL ON A.SAMPLE_ANALYSISID = NUCL.SAMPLE_ANALYSISID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  apexalpha.CI_AAR_CAM_NUCL_RECORD AS NUCL_REC ON A.SAMPLE_ANALYSISID = NUCL_REC.SAMPLE_ANALYSISID AND 
                  NUCL_REC.CAMRECORD = NUCL_TAB.CAMRECORD LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  apexalpha.CI_AAR_CAM_PEAK_RECORD AS PEAK ON A.SAMPLE_ANALYSISID = PEAK.SAMPLE_ANALYSISID AND 
                  NUCL_TAB.NLPEAK = PEAK.CAMRECORD LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  apexalpha.CI_AAR_CAM_PEAK_COMMON AS PEAK_COMMON ON A.SAMPLE_ANALYSISID = PEAK_COMMON.SAMPLE_ANALYSISID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  apexalpha.CI_AAS_ELEMENT_REV AS EL_REV ON PR.ELEMENTID = EL_REV.ELEMENTID AND B.ELEMENT_REVID = EL_REV.ELEMENT_REVID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  apexalpha.CI_AAS_CERTIFICATE AS TRACER ON EL_REV.TRACER_CERTIFICATEID = TRACER.CERTIFICATEID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  apexalpha.CI_AAS_CERTIFICATE AS CONTROL ON EL_REV.CONTROL_CERTIFICATEID = CONTROL.CERTIFICATEID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  dbo.CI_SHL_USER AS APPUSR1 ON S.APPROVAL1_USERID = APPUSR1.USERID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  dbo.CI_SHL_USER AS APPUSR2 ON S.APPROVAL2_USERID = APPUSR2.USERID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  apexalpha.CI_AAR_CAM_SPECIAL_RECORD AS SPEC_REC2 ON A.SAMPLE_ANALYSISID = SPEC_REC2.SAMPLE_ANALYSISID AND 
                  SPEC_REC2.CAMRECORD = 2 LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  apexalpha.CI_AAR_CAM_SPECIAL_RECORD AS SPEC_REC3 ON A.SAMPLE_ANALYSISID = SPEC_REC3.SAMPLE_ANALYSISID AND 
                  SPEC_REC3.CAMRECORD = 3 LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  apexalpha.CI_AAR_CAM_SAMP_COMMON AS SAMP_COM ON A.SAMPLE_ANALYSISID=SAMP_COM.SAMPLE_ANALYSISID
WHERE (S.SAMPLE_DESCRIPTION = '2014-246')
```

This is the SQL code chunk in VB..

```
'--build SQL statement
sSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT S.SAMPLENAME, S.SAMPLE_DESCRIPTION, B.BATCH_NAME, PR.PROC_NAME, S.SAMPLESTATE, S.SAMPLE_QTY, (SELECT MMNT_NAME FROM apexalpha.CI_AAS_MEASUREMENTUNIT WHERE (MEASUREMENTUNITID = S.SAMPLE_QTY_MEASUREMENTUNITID)) AS SAMP_MMNT_NAME, ACQP_CTABULAR.ASTIME, S.SAMPLE_DATE, ACQP_CTABULAR.EREAL, ACQP_CTABULAR.ELIVE, TRACER.CERT_NAME AS TRACER_CERT_NAME, S.TRACER_QTY " & _
"FROM apexalpha.CI_AAD_BATCH AS B INNER JOIN apexalpha.CI_AAD_SAMPLE AS S ON S.BATCHID = B.BATCHID LEFT OUTER JOIN apexalpha.CI_AAS_PROCEDURE AS PR ON B.PROCEDUREID = PR.PROCEDUREID AND B.REVISION = PR.REVISION " & _
"LEFT OUTER JOIN apexalpha.CI_AAD_SAMPLE_ANALYSIS AS A ON S.APPROVED_ANALYSISID = A.SAMPLE_ANALYSISID LEFT OUTER JOIN apexalpha.CI_AAR_CAM_ACQP1_RECORD AS ACQP1 ON A.SAMPLE_ANALYSISID = ACQP1.SAMPLE_ANALYSISID LEFT OUTER JOIN apexalpha.CI_AAR_CAM_PROC1_COMMON AS PROC1 ON A.SAMPLE_ANALYSISID = PROC1.SAMPLE_ANALYSISID LEFT OUTER JOIN apexalpha.CI_AAR_CAM_GEOM_RECORD AS GEOM ON     A.SAMPLE_ANALYSISID = GEOM.SAMPLE_ANALYSISID " & _
"LEFT OUTER JOIN apexalpha.CI_AAR_CAM_ACQP_CTABULAR AS ACQP_CTABULAR ON A.SAMPLE_ANALYSISID = ACQP_CTABULAR.SAMPLE_ANALYSISID LEFT OUTER JOIN apexalpha.CI_AAD_SAMPLE_RUN AS RUN ON RUN.CURRENT_ANALYSISID = S.APPROVED_ANALYSISID LEFT OUTER JOIN apexalpha.CI_AAS_CHAMBER AS C ON RUN.CHAMBERID = C.CHAMBERID LEFT OUTER JOIN apexalpha.CI_AAR_CAM_ANALCNTL1_COMMON AS ANCNTL ON A.SAMPLE_ANALYSISID = ANCNTL.SAMPLE_ANALYSISID " & _
"LEFT OUTER JOIN apexalpha.CI_AAR_CAM_ANALCNTL2_COMMON AS ANCNTL2 ON A.SAMPLE_ANALYSISID = ANCNTL2.SAMPLE_ANALYSISID LEFT OUTER JOIN apexalpha.CI_AAR_CAM_NUCL_RTABULAR AS NUCL_TAB ON A.SAMPLE_ANALYSISID = NUCL_TAB.SAMPLE_ANALYSISID LEFT OUTER JOIN apexalpha.CI_AAR_CAM_NUCL_COMMON AS NUCL ON A.SAMPLE_ANALYSISID = NUCL.SAMPLE_ANALYSISID " & _
"LEFT OUTER JOIN apexalpha.CI_AAR_CAM_NUCL_RECORD AS NUCL_REC ON A.SAMPLE_ANALYSISID = NUCL_REC.SAMPLE_ANALYSISID AND NUCL_REC.CAMRECORD = NUCL_TAB.CAMRECORD LEFT OUTER JOIN apexalpha.CI_AAR_CAM_PEAK_RECORD AS PEAK ON A.SAMPLE_ANALYSISID = PEAK.SAMPLE_ANALYSISID AND  NUCL_TAB.NLPEAK = PEAK.CAMRECORD LEFT OUTER JOIN apexalpha.CI_AAR_CAM_PEAK_COMMON AS PEAK_COMMON ON A.SAMPLE_ANALYSISID = PEAK_COMMON.SAMPLE_ANALYSISID LEFT OUTER JOIN apexalpha.CI_AAS_ELEMENT_REV AS EL_REV ON PR.ELEMENTID = EL_REV.ELEMENTID AND B.ELEMENT_REVID = EL_REV.ELEMENT_REVID " & _
"LEFT OUTER JOIN apexalpha.CI_AAS_CERTIFICATE AS TRACER ON EL_REV.TRACER_CERTIFICATEID = TRACER.CERTIFICATEID LEFT OUTER JOIN apexalpha.CI_AAS_CERTIFICATE AS CONTROL ON EL_REV.CONTROL_CERTIFICATEID = CONTROL.CERTIFICATEID LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.CI_SHL_USER AS APPUSR1 ON S.APPROVAL1_USERID = APPUSR1.USERID LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.CI_SHL_USER AS APPUSR2 ON S.APPROVAL2_USERID = APPUSR2.USERID LEFT OUTER JOIN apexalpha.CI_AAR_CAM_SPECIAL_RECORD AS SPEC_REC2 ON A.SAMPLE_ANALYSISID = SPEC_REC2.SAMPLE_ANALYSISID AND  SPEC_REC2.CAMRECORD = 2 " & _
"LEFT OUTER JOIN apexalpha.CI_AAR_CAM_SPECIAL_RECORD AS SPEC_REC3 ON A.SAMPLE_ANALYSISID = SPEC_REC3.SAMPLE_ANALYSISID AND  SPEC_REC3.CAMRECORD = 3 LEFT OUTER JOIN apexalpha.CI_AAR_CAM_SAMP_COMMON AS SAMP_COM ON A.SAMPLE_ANALYSISID = SAMP_COM.SAMPLE_ANALYSISID " & _
" WHERE SAMPLE_DESCRIPTION = ?;"
```

Answer (score 0):

As I recall there is a limit of lines that you can concatenate by & _. It was approx 28 lines.
Solution is to make two string variables, assign their values keeping limit of lines in mind and produce query string as `query = str1 & str2`. GL!

Comment: The code block that's on the bottom is the one that's being ran in VBA. Its only like 9 lines long. I had it broken up differently before and the error said the max length is 128 characters I believe . So I don't believe the size of the concatenated lines is the problem.  Thanks for the quick reply though.

Comment: Are you trying to execute sSQL with '?' at end?

Comment: The "?" at the end of the code block above is for a parameter. Check the link I posted abovee and you'll see the code that I'm using. The SQL in that example is relatively simple.

Comment: Interesting, I am seeing such parameterization for a first time. Is query without parameter works correctly? Does parameter column consists ' marks in each parameter?

Comment: The query without the parameter does not work. I commented out the "where" clause and the section of code below it that sets up the parameter and it just gives me a run-time error 1004 SQL Syntax error. But the query I pulled straight out of SQL management studio.

Comment: So I've been playing around with it a little today and from what I've found out is it doesn't like the joins on tables. Using one table works like a charm but it just gives me the SQL Syntax error when I have LEFT OUTER JOINS. Does the string that sets up the SQL Query "sSQL" have to be formatted a specific way for joins?

Comment: Third line "S.TRACER_QTYFROM" space missing ;)

Comment: I've tried putting a simple joined table that had only one join and it still said SQL Syntax error. And also, that was a copy paste mistake.

Comment: Well...when tweaking around on another computer with this same query I found that if I comment out the lines `.BackgroundQuery = False` and `.Refresh` It has no problem with the SQL syntax. Howevver, now it gives me an Invalid Parameter error. Any ideas on that one?